# FrameLayout с gravity=center?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ui, framelayout

Всем привет!
Допустим у меня имеется `FrameLayout`, в котором все `View` должны быть в центре. Какой атрибут `FrameLayout` установит все `View` в центр? Пока что выставляю всем дочерним элементам

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Это единственный способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужен именно `FrameLayout`, то только так, как делаете это сейчас. Иначе можно использовать `RelativeLayout`, который поддерживает параметр `android:gravity`:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView is in center of parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, думаю, что `RelativeLayout` "потяжелее", чем `FrameLayout` из-за атрибутов. Но в плане центрирования - в точку, `gravity` поддерживается.

Answer (score -1):

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/CompassMap"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:gravity="center"> // нужный параметр
///////
</FrameLayout>
```